# sort Array in specific filename order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How do I sort the following data in the order I want it?

**The array:**

```
array(4)
{ 
[21]=> string(7) "2-2.pdf" 
[22]=> string(7) "2-3.pdf"
[23]=> string(7) "2-4.pdf" 
[24]=> string(5) "2.pdf" 
}
```

**I want this sort:**

```
2.pdf
2-2.pdf
2-3.pdf
2-4.pdf
```

Comment: And [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) to achieve that? Eg, you can define your own comparison function via [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort)

Comment: But I dont know what I should write in the cmp function.

Comment: This might help you. <?php
   $check_array = array('2-2.pdf','2.pdf','2-3.pdf','2-4.pdf');
  
  function cmp($a, $b)
  {
    return strcmp($a, $b);
  }


usort($check_array, "cmp");

echo "<pre/>"; print_r($check_array);
?>   Just the 2.pdf is the last element of final result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could use usort in this case:

```
$array = [21=> "2-2.pdf", 22=> "2-3.pdf", 23=> "2-4.pdf",24=> "2.pdf", ];
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    $a = str_replace('-', '', $a);
    $b = str_replace('-', '', $b);
    return $a - $b;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
<?php
   $check_array = array('2-2.pdf','2.pdf','2-3.pdf','2-4.pdf');

   function cmp($a, $b)
   {
       $a = preg_replace('/-/','',$a);
       $b = preg_replace('/-/','',$b);
       return strcmp($a, $b);
   }


   usort($check_array, "cmp");


   echo "<pre/>"; print_r($check_array);
 ?>
```

And the result is:

```
<?php Array ( [0] => 2.pdf [1] => 2-2.pdf [2] => 2-3.pdf [3] => 2-4.pdf ) ?>
```